# Execute script in Python2 on Unix Command Line

Tags: python, linux

Yes, I know I can do

```
python2 cal.py
```

What I am asking for is a way to execute it on the command line such as:

```
calpy
```

and then the command afterwards. I put in in a path and when I write cal.py in the command line:

```
/usr/bin/cal.py: line 5: print: command not found
```

I don't want to issue `cal.py` to run my script, I want it to be issued with `calpy`

I'm running Arch Linux if that helps, thanks. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for `bash` to know to run your script via the Python interpreter, you need to put an appropriate [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) at the start. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

tells `bash` to run `/usr/bin/python` with your script as the first argument. I personally prefer

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

which is compatible with [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/). You also need to ensure that the permissions on your script allow it to be executed:

```
~$ chmod +x path/to/cal.py
```

Finally, in order to call `cal` rather than `path/to/cal.py`, you need to remove the `.py` extension and make sure that the directory containing `cal` is in your command search path. I prefer to add `~/bin` to the search path by modifying the `$PATH` environment variable in `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

then put my own executables in `~/bin`. You could also copy (or symlink) `cal` to one of the system-wide binary directories (`/bin` or `/usr/bin`), but I consider it bad practice to mess with system-wide directories unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, you need a couple of things for achive what you want.

First you have to tell your script "How" is going to execute/interpret it. You can do this writting

```
#/usr/bin/env python
```

at the very beggining of the file.

The problem you have is the system is trying to execute the script using `bash`.  And in bash there is no `print` command.

Second you need give execution privileges to your script. And of course if you want to call your script through the command "calcpy", the script has to be called like that.

Comment: I got it to work with another comment. (For you future readers: Arch does NOT have Python Env. Install with `pacman` first.)

Answer (score 1):

Put this (exactly this) as the **first** line of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```