# Shebang line for python does not work at all

Tags: python, zsh, shebang

It is a tough problem. There are several topics for it. But none of them helps me.

I added `#!/usr/bin/env python3` (or python), and run `test.py`, it reported that `zsh: command not found: test.py`. I was confused. I had tried many forms of shebang. Can you help me?

In following error reports, you can see that the reports are different when running it under HOME path and under the parent path of test.py

```
[Scripts] test.py                                                     20:51:04
zsh: command not found: test.py
[Scripts] cd ~                                                        20:51:33
[~] Scripts/test.py                                                   20:51:43
env: python\r: No such file or directory
```

It's not so long since I got the meaning of the shebang line. I hope that it can make my life easy, never writing `python` before `test.py`.

Following is the test code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='test')
parser.add_argument('-o', dest='what', action='store', default='hello', metavar='WHAT')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.what)
```

Following is the configuration.

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:$PATH"
```

And in terminal,

```
[~] which python                                                      20:36:55
python: aliased to python3
[~] which python3                                                     20:36:57
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
ls -l
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 william  staff   273 10 24 20:51 test.py
```

Comment: try `python3 test.py` instead of just `test.py`?

Comment: @cryptnome: thats what the shebang should translate to

Comment: @cryptonome I know that. I just want to use shebang to omit `python3`

Comment: what about `./test.py`

Comment: @William Song: try `./test.py`

Comment: Make sure the script has execution rights and run it with command `./test.py`

Comment: Sounds like `test.py` is not in your PATH. Try using relative (or absolute) path, as others have suggested.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute script in Python2 on Unix Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29234411/execute-script-in-python2-on-unix-command-line)

Comment: @linluk https://stackoverflow.com/a/2429517/10254804 shebang is just there to help the shell locates the correct python interpreter in that env, in the case of multiple interpreters installed. `./test.py` is the right way, but `chmod` needs to be set for correctly (755) for test.py to be seen as executable.

Comment: @linluk [Scripts] ./test.py                                                   20:57:25
env: python\r: No such file or directory

Comment: @Antwane No, the old topic did not help me.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the directory of `test.py` is not in your `PATH`, you will need to use either a relative or absolute path, and ensure that the script has execution privileges.

```
$ chmod u+x test.py
$ ./test.py
```

Should execute properly.

---

With the error `env: python3\r: No such file or directory`: the file is using "CRLF" newlines: `\r\n`, while a single `\n` is expected. So `zsh` is splitting on the first `\n`, leaving the shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env python3\r`, with `python3\r` obviously not in your `PATH`. If you change the line endings with `unix2dos test.py`, that should fix the issue as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569997/how-to-find-out-line-endings-in-a-text-file).

Comment: ls -l
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 william  staff   273 10 24 20:51 test.py

Comment: @WilliamSong what is the result from using `./test.py` instead of `test.py` without the relative path?

Comment: env: python3\r: No such file or directory

Comment: @WilliamSong it looks like a newlines issue: you can see the kind of line endings with `file test.py` on *nix type systems (including macOS). Make sure the file uses Unix newlines instead of CRLF newlines

Comment: @WilliamSong I can't tell you why the `\r\n` is there, but that's the probable cause of your current problem. If you fix your line endings it should work now, from what I can tell.

Comment: I use `dos2unix` to translate it. But it's too much trouble when translating the codes in many files. Can I set it in sublime or vim? I use Mac.

Comment: @WilliamSong that sounds like a great thing to ask in a search engine. This answer might help you get on the right track with Sublime Text: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11900286/3882704

Answer (score 0):

After adding the shebang to your python file:

- Make the file executable `chmod +x test.py`
- Run the file while in the directory it exists `./test.py`